# Splitting data set into training and testing sets on recommender systems

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, cross-validation

I have implemented a recommender system based upon matrix factorization techniques. I want to evaluate it.

I want to use 10-fold-cross validation with All-but-one protocol (https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/0fcc/45600283abca12ea2f422e3fb2575f4c7fc0.pdf).

My data set has the following structure:

```
user_id,item_id,rating
1,1,2
1,2,5
1,3,0
2,1,5
...
```

It's confusing for me to think how the data is going to be splitted, because I can't put some triples (user,item,rating) in the testing set. For example, if I select the triple (2,1,5) to the testing set and this is the only rating user 2 has made, there won't be any other information about this user and the trained model won't predict any values for him.

Considering this scenario, how should I do the splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite correct in your basic logic: if you have only one observation in a class, you *must* include that in the training set for the model to have any validity in that class.

However, dividing the input into these classes depends on the interactions among various observations.  Can you identify classes of data, such as the "only rating" issue you mentioned?  As you find other small classes, you'll also need to ensure that you have enough of those observations in your training data.

Unfortunately, this is a process that's tricky to automate.  Most one-time applications simply have to hand-pick those observations from the data, and then distribute the others per normal divisions.  This does have a problem that the special cases are over-represented in the training set, which can detract somewhat from the normal cases in training the model.

Do you have the capability of tuning the model as you encounter later data?  This is generally the best way to handle sparse classes of input.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a language or toolset so I cannot give you a concise answer that is 100% applicable to you, but here's the approach I took to solve this same exact problem.

I'm working on a recommender system using Treasure Data (i.e. Presto) and implicit observations, and ran into a problem with my matrix where some users and items were not present. I had to re-write the algorithm to split the observations into train and test so that every user and every item would be represented in the training data. For the description of my algorithm I assume there are more users than items. If this is not true for you then just swap the two. Here's my algorithm.

1. Select one observation for each user
2. For each item that has only one observation and has not already been selected from the previous step select one observation
3. Merge the results of the previous two steps together.
   This should produce a set of observations that covers all of the users and all of the items.
4. Calculate how many observations you need to fill your training set (generally 80% of the total number of observations)
5. Calculate how many observations are in the merged set from step 3.
   The difference between steps 4 and 5 is the number of remaining observations necessary to fill the training set.
6. Randomly select enough of the remaining observations to fill the training set.
7. Merge the sets from step 3 and 6: this is your training set.
8. The remaining observations is your testing set.

As I mentioned, I'm doing this using Treasure Data and Presto so the only tool I have at my disposal is SQL, common table expressions, temporary tables, and Treasure Data workflow.

Comment: But, do you have any reference that can argue your view point ? I would be glad to read a paper or an article about it ! Thanks

Comment: Let me see what I can come up with. Your training set needs to contain enough observations that the matrix factorization training can do what its supposed to: discern the latent factors of each user and item. Without a single observation for a user or item renders the training useless, and even just one observation generally is not enough.
I have since re-worked the logic to only consider those users and items that have, at a minimum, 10 observations.

Answer (score 0):

collaborative filtering (matrix factorization) can't have a good recommendation for an unseen user with no feedback. Nevertheless, an evaluation should consider this case and take it into account.

One thing you can do is to report performance for all test users, just test users with some feedback and just unseen users with no feedback.

So I'd say keep the test, train split random but evaluate separately for unseen users.

More info [here](http://fastml.com/evaluating-recommender-systems/).